arXiv CS.AI and CS.CL endorsement
I have been working with a newly created startup as a machine learning researcher. I've been working on two research papers snd they were reviewed by my professor st my university and they told me some issues that I needed to address and the final result is done. However, it has been a major issue as in how to publish these papers in arXiv since I don't know any of my professors who publishes in arXiv. I need an endorser for these papers. Since I'm in a startup environment, there's no other researcher than me.
Thank you in advance

This question is similar to: How to find an arXiv endorser. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I agree. There is no question mark in your post. If the question is "How do I find an endorser?", then please see the link. If the question is "will someone here endorse me?", we don't do that. If the question is something else, please [edit] your post to contain a question. (Also, why can't the professor who reviewed your paper endorse you?).
